# How to get Finder in Lion to set group permissions to read/write by default?

Tags: macos, finder, permission

To have group permissions set to read/write by default in Snow Leopard and Leopard, I used `/etc/launchd-user.conf` to set the umask to 002.

This still works in Lion in every app *except* the Finder. Actually, Lion's Finder does apply the umask when setting permissions, but if the group (or everyone) bit is set to zero, the Finder will treat it like it's a 2, which makes new folders' group permissions read only.

Out of curiosity, I did try using the old technique I used in OS X 10.4, using the `defaults` command to set the umask and NSUmask, but that doesn't work (which was expected).

I'm hoping to find a solution without having to use ACLs.

Does anyone know of another way to get the Finder in Lion to set group permissions to read/write by default?

Comment: Are you making folders with Finder? Or copying files?

Comment: @bmike This is only for new folders (and new alias files). Copying files & folders will retain group read/write permissions from the original.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BatChmod for setting permissions of files. You can also use it to chmod a batch of files. Download link: http://download.cnet.com/BatChmod/3000-2248_4-19574.html